# Append Incremental Number to a Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a field in my Database that stores a product-page.html name for each product in my product table.

The issue I have is the CMS i'm using allows for duplicate products, and when uploading I'm getting duplicate page names for products highlighted. This is caused due to a setting issue in the CMS.

To resolve it...

Is there away to append an incremental value to each record containing the page name of a product to make them all unique?

i.e.

- product-page-1.html
- product-page-2.html
- Etc.

Whereby the value 1, 2 is being created via SQL statement to make all the page names unique

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: To help the community answer your question, could you paste the code generated when you right-click on your table and select Script Table As > Create To > New query window.

Comment: The site I working on is using CMS called SellerDeck that uses an Access 2000 database. The duplicate page issue comes when upload via the CMS as there's no database online the pages become static on upload with Perl for shopping cart control. That's why if I was able to append a unique number to each page name for a product it would resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your table called `page-id` or similar.

Modify your `INSERT` statement as follows:

```
DECLARE @NewPageName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'your page name'
DECLARE @NewProductName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'your product name'

DECLARE @NewPageId = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SELECT ISNULL(MAX(page-id), 0) + 1 FROM your-table WHERE page-name = @NewPageName)

INSERT INTO 
    your-table
    (
        product-name
        , page-name
        , page-id
        , ...
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
        @NewProductName
        , @NewPageName
        , @NewPageId
        , ...
    )
```

Now, you can concatenate `page-name` and `page-id` in your code to retrieve the full page name.

```
SELECT 
    page-name + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), page-id) + '.html' AS full-page-name
FROM 
    your-table 
WHERE 
    product-name = 'your product name'
```

Note: I am currently guessing what your table and columns are named.

I have requested more information so that I may revisit this answer and supply you with actual code in the future.

Comment: I basically want to add an incremental number to a field that contains product page names to make them all unique. page-name[incremental-number].html . Is there SQL for doing that?